# oracle sql compare times where > 1 on single work date

Tags: sql, oracle

The `not like` operator is not suitable for comparing values where the number of values is > 1 on a single work date. In the example below the records in the first 2 rows are a match (bold=bold, italic=italic) and should NOT appear in the output.  The issue is caused by the ‘not like’ operator looping.

i have simplified the code as follows:

```
  SELECT e.EMP_NAME AS APS,
         TO_CHAR (ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS Work_Date,
         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_START_TIME), 'hh24:mi') AS Leave_Start_Time,
         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi') AS Leave_End_Time,
         TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi') AS shift_brk_Start,
         TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                  'hh24:mi')
            AS shift_brk_end
    FROM work.WORK_SUMMARY ws,
         work.employee e,
         work.work_detail wd,
         work.TIME_CODE tc,
         work.shift s,
         work.shift_break sb,
         work.EMPLOYEE_SCHEDULE es
   WHERE     ws.emp_id = e.emp_id
         AND wd.WRKD_MINUTES < s.SHFT_VAL1 ---sum workd minutes less than shift id actual shift minutes
         AND ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE BETWEEN '09-Jul-2013' AND '09-Jul-2013'
         AND wd.WRKS_ID = ws.WRKS_ID
         AND tc.TCODE_name IN
                ('COMP', 'SL COMP PEN', 'ARB','LUC',
                 'CMF', 'MREP', 'WSSL', 'RL',
                 'CBK', 'JUR', 'LSL', 'LSLT',
                 'LWPNC', 'LWPS', 'LWPTC', 'LWPU',
                 'LWOP', 'ML', 'MLHP', 'NWPTC',
                 'PAT', 'PL', 'SD', 'MSP',
                 'SUS', 'SUSW', 'WIT', 'CMPA',
                 'ABC', 'ABN', 'BER', 'COM',
                 'COMWP', 'IS', 'EXL', 'LFI',
                 'MER', 'NCD', 'PCLC', 'PCLS',
                 'PSLC', 'PSLN', 'PSLW', 'PSWO',
                 'PSLP', 'PURL', 'STU', 'UA',
                 'GRTW')
         AND wd.TCODE_ID = tc.TCODE_ID
         AND ws.PAYGRP_ID IN ('10023')
         AND ws.WRKS_AUTHORIZED = 'Y'
         AND e.EMP_TERMINATION_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
         --and e.emp_name in('1100376801','1100590701')
         AND ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE = es.WORK_DATE
         AND ws.emp_id = es.emp_id
         AND ws.shft_id = es.EMPSKD_ACT_SHIFT_ID
         AND es.EMPSKD_ACT_SHIFT_ID = s.SHFT_ID
         AND s.SHFT_ID = sb.SHFT_ID
         AND (   (    TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi') <=
                         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_START_TIME), 'hh24:mi')
                  AND TO_CHAR (
                           sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START
                         + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                         'hh24:mi') >
                         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_START_TIME), 'hh24:mi'))
              OR (    TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi') <
                         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi')
                  AND TO_CHAR (
                           sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START
                         + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                         'hh24:mi') > TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi'))
              OR (    TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi') >
                         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_START_TIME), 'hh24:mi')
                  AND TO_CHAR (
                           sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START
                         + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                         'hh24:mi') < TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi'))
              OR (    TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi') =
                         TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi')
                  AND TO_CHAR (
                           sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START
                         + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                         'hh24:mi') = TO_CHAR ( (wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'hh24:mi')))
GROUP BY e.EMP_NAME,
         ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE,
         wd.WRKD_end_TIME,
         wd.WRKD_START_TIME,
         sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START,
         TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694,
                  'hh24:mi');
```

Result:

```
APS         WORK_DATE   LEAVE_START_TIME LEAVE_END_TIME SHIFT_BRK_START SHIFT_BRK_END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
40151401  09.07.2013  10:00            13:00          10:30           11:00
40200001  09.07.2013  09:00            12:51          10:00           10:30
40447701  09.07.2013  09:30            14:15          10:00           10:30
40492101  09.07.2013  15:00            20:10          16:00           16:30
61037301  09.07.2013  10:35            14:15          11:00           11:30
64173401  09.07.2013  09:30            14:15          10:00           10:30
```

The issue is that i am expecting to see a record for employee 1100376801.
The reason I can't see the record is because the times for the missing record fall over midnight, i.e **00:51.**  How can i format the 'datetime' fields differently so that times over midnight are picked up, i.e. where the SHIFT_BRK_START and SHIFT_BRK_END times span or fall within the LEAVE_START_TIME and LEAVE_END_TIME.

Expected result: in addition to the results returned above i should also see the following record:

```
APS         WORK_DATE   LEAVE_START_TIME LEAVE_END_TIME SHIFT_BRK_START SHIFT_BRK_END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11003701  09.07.2013  20:00            **0:51**       19:30           19:45
```

**RESOLUTION:**

```
and 
(

(to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') < (wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') > (wd.WRKD_start_TIME))---1


OR(to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') =(wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') = (wd.WRKD_end_TIME))--4

OR(to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') =(wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') > (wd.WRKD_end_TIME))---5

OR(to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') =(wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') <(wd.WRKD_end_TIME))---5

OR (to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') > (wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') <= (wd.WRKD_end_TIME))---3

OR (to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') > (wd.WRKD_START_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') < (wd.WRKD_end_TIME) and 
to_date(to_char(wd.WRKD_START_TIME, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '' || to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') > (wd.WRKD_end_TIME))---2

)
```

Comment: I think you could better use `CASE` statements for checking.

Comment: I tried using 'case' but still have issue where there are more than 2 records on 1 date.

Comment: you might've problem in joining, could you show the result of two inner queries you used?

Comment: the 1st inner query result (a_emp_break):

Comment: APS, WORK_DATE, START_BREAK, END_BREAK, MINUTES 1100376801 08.07.2013 21:30 21:45 15 1100376801 08.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15 1100376801 09.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15

Comment: APS, WORK_DATE, START_BREAK, END_BREAK, MINUTES              1100376801 08.07.2013 21:30 21:45 15                       1100376801 08.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15                        1100376801 09.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15

Comment: the 2nd inner query result (B_shift_break):                                                                                                                         APS,WORK_DATE,SHIFT_BRK_START,SHIFT_BRK_END,SHFTBRK_MINUTES 
1100376801 08.07.2013 21:30 21:45 15 

1100376801 08.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15 

1100376801 09.07.2013 21:30 21:45 15 

1100376801 09.07.2013 19:30 19:45 15

Comment: I have updated and simplified the initial sql and problem issue please review

Comment: You should not compare date with `to_char`, convert the date conditions with `to_date()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Its still not clear about your requirement and data

Here are some points to check:

- check the two below queries with `'ALTER SESSION NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`

> ```
> (e.EMP_NAME || '_' || TO_CHAR(ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy') || '_' ||to_char(min(wd.WRKD_START_TIME), 'HH24:MI')|| '_' ||to_char(max(wd.WRKD_end_TIME), 'HH24:MI')) as test
> ```

```
(e.EMP_NAME || '_' || TO_CHAR(ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy') || '_' ||to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START,'HH24:MI')|| '_' ||to_char(sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES+1)*.000694, 'HH24:MI')) as test
```

- The condition for outermost query might not work as you expected, 
  `not like` operator will fail as your inner query for the column `test` is different.

> 

```
where a_emp_break.test not like b_shift_break.test
                         and a_emp_break.APS=b_shift_break.APS
                         and a_emp_break.Work_Date = b_shift_break.Work_Date
```

- you didn't mention the date you needed anywhere.

**updating**

- check with the below outer query again:
  `TO_CHAR (sb.SHFTBRK_DEF_START + (sb.SHFTBRK_MINUTES + 1) * .000694, 'hh24:mi') AS shift_brk_end`
- `AND ws.WRKS_WORK_DATE BETWEEN '09-Jul-2013' AND '09-Jul-2013'` check the above includes the desired ids.
- check again with the conditions with the to_date() funcition that accurating with `<` and `>` symbols.

Thanks.

Comment: I have simplified the script as follows:

Comment: i finally got it working - as you suggested i had to include to_date.  I have updated the SQL to show amended code

Comment: It still seems very complex in your condition with date, you could use PL/SQL, lead(), lag() functions, for reference. to make the code clear for future use.

Comment: thankyou, i did try using lead & lag functions however could not get the desired result